# Problem with CadTools plugin in QGIS 2.2

Tags: qgis, plugins

I've just downloaded the CadTools plugin from QGIS Plugins page (can't do this through QGIS itself as I'm behind a proxy) and after installation I keep getting an error saying that it "*Couldn't load plugin cadtools due an error when calling its classFactory() method*".

Looking further into this there appears to be a problem with a line in the cadtools.py file relating to *self.localPtah.pluginPath*.  pluginPath seems to be set to look in the *i18n* subfolder but I don't appear to have this subfolder in my installation.

Has anybody else had a similar issue with CadTools or have I just missed a step with the installation??

Comment: Are you sure you have downloaded the Qgis2 version of the plugin?

Comment: Hi Andre, I've downloaded version 0.6.2 from https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ and according to the metedata it should work with QGIS 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not the first with this problem:

https://github.com/geopython/CadTools/issues/5

My regular 0.6.2 installation also has no i18n folder, and I remember getting a similar error message without using the plugin at all. I then deactivated the plugin until I needed it again.

You can download the master zip with the i18n folder from https://github.com/geopython/CadTools and insert it manually into your CadTools folder.

Feel free to add your case to the issue.

Comment: Hi Andre, many thanks for that.  Downloaded from github and everything seems ok :)

Comment: Well, it still is a bug of the plugin that the i18n folder is not included on the plugins.qgis.org site.